# Value in DOM element isn't updated meanwhile in component updated

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I'm currently facing an issue in updating a value in the DOM.

**header.component.ts**

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  purchaseSummary = 0;

  constructor(private someService: SomeService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.someService.summary.subscribe(
      observer => this.purchaseSummary = observer
    );
  }

}
```

**header.html**

```
<a>{{purchaseSummary}}</a>
```

**some.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class SomeService {

  summary = new Subject<number>();

}
```

**purchase.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class PurchaseService {

  products: { name: string, price: number }[] = [];

  constructor(private someService: SomeService) {
  }

  addProduct(product: { name: string, price: number }) {
    this.products.push(product);
    this.someService.summary.next(this.countSummaryPrice());
  }

  deleteProduct(id: number) {
    this.products.splice(id, 1);
    this.someService.summary.next(this.countSummaryPrice());
  }

  countSummaryPrice() {
    let sum = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < this.products.length; i++) {
      sum += this.products[i].price;
    }
    return sum;
  }

}
```

When I'm executing in another DOM **PurchaseService#addProduct** it normally increase my value in **header.html**. 
When I'm trying to delete product by executing **PurchaseService#deleteProduct** it delete item from array, but value in **header.html** isn't changed. Also I'm tried to **console.log()** result of **PurchaseService#countSummaryPrice** in **PurchaseService#deleteProduct** method. It logging **expected value**, but not changing it at **header.html**

**UPD:**
Forgot about place, where it's displayed:
**purchase.component.html**

```
<table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th >#</th>
    <th >Product</th>
    <th >Price</th>
    <th >&</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody *ngFor="let product of products; let i = index">
  <th scope="row">{{i+1}}</th>
  <td>{{product.name}}</td>
  <td>{{product.price}}</td>
  <td><button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="onDelete(i)">X</button></td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And **purchase.component.ts**

```
export class PurchaseComponent implements OnInit {

  products: { name: string, price: number }[];

  constructor(private purchaseService: PurchaseService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.products = this.purchaseService.products;
  }

  onDelete(id: number) {
    this.purchaseService.deleteProduct(id);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data you have is 'products', 
Try this to update when products are deleted.

```
 deleteProduct(id: number) {
    this.removeProduct(productId);
    this.someService.summary.next(this.countSummaryPrice());
  }

removeProduct(productId) {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.products.length; i++) {
      if (this.products[i].id === productId) {
        this.products.splice(i, 1);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately your tip doesn't helped me :(